# SendBird : Is there an option to disable channel creation for users

Tags: sendbird

I am trying to see if there is a way to configure an application in sendbird ( not the client app but the app configuration at sendbird ) to not allow users to create channels.

We are wanting to manage the users for a channel based on our own system's needs ( mostly around dynamic groups of users and it looks like sendbird does not support such a thing and only has user to channel relations )

By disabling channel creation for users we can write extra logic into our chat client to communicate with our own APIs for adding dynamic groups of users and we then send the requests from out platform to sendbird to add or remove users who belong to those groups for the desired channels or if the groups change on our side when people add and remove users then we can maintain a sync for sendbirds channels to ensure the correct users persist in the channels.

If my understanding is wrong and Sendbird does support dynamic groups then please advise and I will prefer this option else if someone knows how to configure an app for sendbird ( not the client app code but in the configuration of the app at sendbird ) to not allow channel creation by users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SendBird SDK - [Authenticated users](https://docs-st.sendbird.com/javascript/authentication#3_connect_to_sendbird_server_with_a_user_id_and_an_access_token) have access to their own channels only. Furthermore, it is also possible to specifically restrict the create channel method at the individual user level. If you contact SendBird support (support@sendbird.com) they are able to help with this requirement.

Regarding dynamic groups. SendBird has group channels which can have their member lists controlled by SendBird's platform API. This seems to fit with your requirements. New users can be programmatically [invited](https://docs-st.sendbird.com/platform/group_channel#3_invite_members) to, or [removed](https://docs-st.sendbird.com/platform/group_channel#3_leave_a_channel) from a group [channel](https://docs-st.sendbird.com/platform/channel_type#3_group_channel).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think we will be needing that blanket disabling of such functionality as we need to retain logic on our side to decide on when users can create channels and for whom they can invite to the channel. Using the Platform API will allow us to do this but just need that feature disabled for clients. The group behaviour of SendBird with group channels unfortunately is not enough as we have users who can belong to groups but our chats need to comprise of users and multiple groups that respect our definition of users for each group. This is ok as we can handle via PlatformAPI